# setVisible in Java Applet not working

Tags: java, applet

I am writing a Java applet, in my applet I simply call setVisible() to control the visibility of some panels.

For example:

```
pnlAddUser.setVisible(true);
```

but sometimes showing panel does not work. and when I just click on the border of Applet Viewer window, the panel appears.

I used:

- invalidate()
- setSize(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight())
- this.repaint(this.getGraphics());
- pnlAddUser.repaint();

but it doesn't work.

Edit: I should mention, I am using a JTree and when a TreeNode is selected, I show or hide some panels according to the type of the node.

Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: You can try `this.repaint()` on the `applet`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it does not work.

Comment: Can you give some information about how these panels are associated with their container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Not good but it works.

I added the code:

```
public void repaintAgain() {
    setSize(this.getWidth() - 1, this.getHeight() - 1);
    setSize(this.getWidth() + 1, this.getHeight() + 1);
}
```

whenever I want to repaint, use this.

Comment: working for me also.... I saw this also a bug: http://segal.org/java/ShowComponent/index.html